# Why is Python waiting, if it is not supposed to be?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygame

I made a game with Python 3 and PyGame. Now I wanted to add a new mob, which worked well, except one thing:

I wanted to give the mob an animation, made of pictures, that switch.
That you see them switching I imported `time` and made this:

```py
def walk(self):
    self.img_1
    time.sleep(0.2)
    self.img_2
    time.sleep(0.2)

def update(self):
    # stuff
    self.walk()
```

When I run it, Python waits and hangs up. But I don't want it to wait. I just want it to wait between switching the pictures.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's waiting because you told it to wait.

Comment: And what is `self.img_1` supposed to do?

Comment: I want it to wait between switching images. (that it doesn't run through it in milliseconds). Not waiting to start the hole game. And I definded self._img1 ... in another file, it just loads the image.

Answer (score 4):

`time.sleep()` pauses whatever thread runs it, so no other code will execute until the wait is completed.

What you'll want to do is to store information on the state of the animation and change it by calling `time.time()` or something similar to measure how much time has passed and update the picture based on that.

Comment: how can I tell python, how long to wait, if I use time.time(). If I do sth like: time.time(0.2) I'm getting a TypeError. Thanks

Comment: time.time() doesn't work that way. It polls the system clock and returns the current time expressed as a floating point number. You see your program is most likely a single thread of execution where the program is run in order. So if you have your program sleep it does absolutely nothing until the sleep is completed. otherwise it runs through a loop of activity which causes the update function of yours to be run every so often. So when you do an update you need to calculate the amount of time that has passed since the last update and use that to determine the correct picture to draw.

Comment: Very well expanded. Thanks. How do I do that with the calculating? I can't only write time.time() between my images, because then it runs through it in milliseconds and I am seeing nothing.

Comment: I don't have enough characters to fully explain in a comment. There are multiple ways to do it but you need to store the current time in a variable and then calculate the time change between update calls each time it's called. Another option is to calculate how long an update cycle takes and then sleep for an amount of time that makes each update equally long (but for which the sleep is really short like 1/60th of a second.) take a look at these links: 
 https://riptutorial.com/pygame/topic/3959/getting-started-with-pygame https://dr0id.bitbucket.io/legacy/pygame_tutorial04.html